# How to use jQuery scrollTop and scroll down

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

How do I use `scrollTop` and scroll down in jQuery?

```
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">

    <div class="items">
        texttext
    </div>
    <div class="prev button">prev</div>
    <div class="next button">next</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've created:
[image]

I want to use `scrollTop`:

[image]

I want to scroll down:

[image]

and more scroll:

[image]

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/XEMBZ/

Comment: why you update myquestion.. oh god!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        $('#scrolltotop').fadeIn(200);
    } else {
        $('#scrolltotop').fadeOut(200);
    }
});

// Animate the scroll to top
$('#scrolltotop').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
})
    });
    </script>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="scrolltotop">scroll top</a>
```

Comment: please give me jfiddle

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/raamaragavan/PfnMx/1/

check this jsfiddle link for output,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('#top').fadeIn(200);
} else {
    $('#top').fadeOut(200);
}
});

// Animate the scroll to top
$('#top').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
})
});
```

Comment: i wanted scolltop and scrolldown are prev and next.**What u mean?**

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to top

```
var pixelFromTop = 0;     
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pixelFromTop  }, 1);
```

So when page open it is automatically scroll to top after 1 milisecond

Scroll some pixels from top

```
 var pixelFromTop = 500;     
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: pixelFromTop  }, 1);
```

So when page open it is automatically scroll down after 1 milisecond